# how to solve pub upgrade failed (1) for flutter web?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I am setting up my flutter for web but flutter pub upgrade failed.

this is the error `Could not find a file named "packages/flutter_web/pubspec.yaml" in https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web 7a4c33425ddd78c54aba07d86f3f9a4a0051769b.`How do i go about solving this. This error keeps me from running my web app. included is my pubspec.yaml file i hope this will help you help me. thank you in advance.

My Pubspec.yaml file

````
description: An app built using Flutter for web

environment:
  # You must be using Flutter >=1.5.0 or Dart >=2.3.0
  sdk: '>=2.3.0-dev.0.1 <3.0.0'

dependencies:
  flutter_web: any
  flutter_web_ui: any

dev_dependencies:
  build_runner: ^1.4.0
  build_web_compilers: ^2.0.0
  pedantic: ^1.0.0

dependency_overrides:
  flutter_web:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web
  flutter_web_ui:
    git:
      url: https://github.com/flutter/flutter_web
      path: packages/flutter_web_ui```
````

Comment: @RichardHeap any thoughts on what might cause this error...?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After a whole day of playing around. just make sure everything is updated to the latest versions. go into you git cache directory and clean it... `C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Roaming\Pub\Cache\git\cache` i hope this helps someone not to waste a whole day like i did...